# Facebook Comments changes the stylesheet on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, styles, responsive-design, facebook-comments

I'm coding a responsive website and it is the first time that I'm using Facebook Comments tool. Everything is correct except when I access it on mobile.

Facebook Comments generates a new stylesheet for mobile. I'm looking for some code that disables or ignore this new stylesheet.

Screenshots...
 - [on desktop](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8ei21o1zvt11iw/desktop.jpg)
 - [on mobile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf53gl37jnhaeku/mobile.png)

Comment: I got it! Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS of your own to over ride the FB css and make the comments box responsive. Just add this to your CSS

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style] {max-width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vector! But this doesn't solve the problem. This code is only for the width 100%. I am using it.

Comment: I was supposed to type `max-width`, edited it now. If it doesn't fix it then i'll take a look when i'm next at my pc (on mobile phone at mo)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! To disable the stylesheet for mobile, we must insert a new attribute (mobile="false") in HTML code.

```
<div class="facebook_comments">
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-mobile="false"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

\o/